# How to make an button to make a confirmation box to do a task in Jquery and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In my HTML below `button` and `<p>`is used..

```
<button  class="btn btn-info" id ="btn">submit</button>
<p></p>
```

I have used Jquery to run my script whenever I click submit button as follows,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn").click(function(){
          $('#loading').show();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'testme.php',
                success: function(data) {
                    //alert(data);
                    $("p").text(data);
                    $('#loading').hide();

                }
            });
   });
});
```

This works fine and I could see the loading screen until `testme.php` executes.

Now I need to make a confirmation box as below before executes...

[image]

Is some one clicks Yes I need to go ahead and run my `testme.php` if not I need to close the window box.

I have checked some examples in below site but could not find a method to combine it with my existing code. Can someone help me on this case?

https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Sliding-Confirm-Dialog-Plugin-with-jQuery-Bootstrap-Confirm/

Thanks in Advance!

Update:

Here is my complete code  after  Rory McCrossan's answer But seems there is an issue
...

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Colombo");//set you countary name from below timezone list
// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>Anomaly Monitoring Dashboard-International Voice</title>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm//vega@5"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm//vega-lite@4.8.1"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm//vega-embed@6"></script>
    

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Sliding-Confirm-Dialog-Plugin-with-jQuery-Bootstrap-Confirm/jquery.confirm.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  
</head>





<body style=" background-color: #F0F8FF">

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <h2>Anomaly Dashboard</h2>
    <ul>
        
        
    </ul> 
    
</div>
    <div class="main_content">

     <div id="loading" >
         <img id="loading-image" src="./assets/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." />
     </div>
       <?php
            include "adminHeader.php";
        ?>
  


<div class="mytabs">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li class="active"><a href="#summarytab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Summary</a></li>
        <li><a href="#SSWtab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">tab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#SBCtab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">tab2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#ctbtab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">tab3</a></li>

  <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Web <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#jquerytab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">jQuery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#bootstab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Bootstrap</a></li>
                <li><a href="#htmltab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">HTML</a></li>
            </ul>
  </li>  
  
 </ul>
</div>



<div class="mytabs">
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="summarytab">Write something for home tab</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="SSWtab">
   

  
    <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
     
                <form method="POST">
                    <div class="mb-3">
          

            <button  type='button'  id ="btnnew">submit</button>
            <p></p>
            
                    </div>

                    
                </form>
            </div>

    
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="SBCtab">C# is also a programming language</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="ctbtab">MySQL is a databased mostly used for web applications.</div>

  <div class="tab-pane" id="jquerytab">jQuery content here </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="bootstab">Bootstrap Content here
  <ul>
  <li>Bootstrap forms</li>
  <li>Bootstrap buttons</li>
  <li>Bootstrap navbar</li>
  <li>Bootstrap footer</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="htmltab">Hypertext Markup Language</div>  
  
</div>
</div>


 


  </div>







    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>


<script>



  $(window).load(function() {
    $('#loading').hide();
  });


$("#btnnew").confirm({
  
  title: "Delete confirmation",
  text: "This is very dangerous, you shouldn't do it! Are you really really sure?",
  confirm: function(button) {        
    console.log('AJAX request in progress...');
    
    $('#loading').show();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'testme.php',
      success: function(data) {
        $("p").text(data);
      },
      complete: function() {      
        $('#loading').hide();
      }
    });
    
  },
  cancel: function(button) {
    console.log("You aborted the operation.");
  },
  confirmButton: "Yes I am",
  cancelButton: "No"
});




  

    
</script>
```

Comment: In your link, use the second code example, then put the `$.ajax()` call which you currently have, in to the `confirm` handler function.

Comment: Tried.. But failed. Could you please help me with an Answer? need to show #loading as well..

Comment: Sure, added an example for you.

Answer (score 1):

In the link in your question, it's the second example which is relevant to you. That will bind the event handler to the first button to display the confirmation dialog. From there you can place your `$.ajax()` logic within the `confirm` handler for it to be invoked when the user confirms the dialog.

Also note in the example below that I hide the loading spinner in the `complete` callback. This is to ensure that you don't freeze the UI in a permanent loading state if the AJAX request fails.

```js
$("#btn").confirm({
  title: "Delete confirmation",
  text: "This is very dangerous, you shouldn't do it! Are you really really sure?",
  confirm: function(button) {        
    console.log('AJAX request in progress...');
    
    /* Commented for this demo only   
    $('#loading').show();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'testme.php',
      success: function(data) {
        $("p").text(data);
      },
      complete: function() {      
        $('#loading').hide();
      }
    });
    */
  },
  cancel: function(button) {
    console.log("You aborted the operation.");
  },
  confirmButton: "Yes I am",
  cancelButton: "No"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Sliding-Confirm-Dialog-Plugin-with-jQuery-Bootstrap-Confirm/jquery.confirm.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<button class="btn btn-info" id="btn">submit</button>
<p></p>
```

Comment: Thanks! I have used this same.. But my page is refreshing only I cant see the loading as well as after that echo as well.. Any help?

Comment: That sounds like your `#btn` element is submitting a form. I'd suggest adding the `type="button"` attribute to it, removing it from within the `form` element, or making it another element entirely, such as an `<a />`.

Comment: type='button' worked... Now Page is not refreshing... But I could not see the popup as well as the echo. Seems both pop and execution dont work

Comment: In which case there is some HTML or JS interfering with the operation of the code, as you can see in the example above it works fine in isolation. I'd suggest starting a new question about this, including all relevant code.

Comment: Thans.. since I could not post questions in a row, I made an update to my question. Hope you could kindly check..

Comment: I made an separate question..