# How to make a pop window when pressed button using Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have already raised this question with and I have found the answers as well here.
[How to make an button to make a confirmation box to do a task in Jquery and HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72627703/how-to-make-an-button-to-make-a-confirmation-box-to-do-a-task-in-jquery-and-html/72627948?noredirect=1#comment128293024_72627948)

I could see the answers are correct as in the output. But whenever I used this same code to my existing code I could not see the popup window and my test php script is not running. Can someone show what interfered here in my original code?

My Code...

```
<?php
    // Initialize the session
    session_start();
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Colombo");//set you countary name from below timezone list
    // Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
    if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
        header("location: login.php");
        exit;
    }
    ?>
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    
        <title>Dashboard</title>
    
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Sliding-Confirm-Dialog-Plugin-with-jQuery-Bootstrap-Confirm/jquery.confirm.js"></script>
    <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm//vega@5"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm//vega-lite@4.8.1"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm//vega-embed@6"></script>
    
    
    
      
    </head>
    
    
    
    
    
    <body style=" background-color: #F0F8FF">
    
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="sidebar">
        <h2>Dashboard</h2>
        
    
     
        
    </div>
        <div class="main_content">
    
         <div id="loading" >
             <img id="loading-image" src="./assets/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." />
         </div>
           <?php
                include "adminHeader.php";
            ?>
      
    
    
    <div class="mytabs">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li class="active"><a href="#summarytab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Summary</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SSWtab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">SSW KPI Monitoring</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SBCtab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">SBC KPI Monitoring</a></li>
            <li><a href="#ctbtab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">CTB KPI Monitoring</a></li>
    
      <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Web <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#jquerytab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">jQuery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#bootstab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Bootstrap</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#htmltab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">HTML</a></li>
                </ul>
      </li>  
      
     </ul>
    </div>
    
    
    
    <div class="mytabs">
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="summarytab">Write something for home tab</div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="SSWtab">
       
      
      
        <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
         
                    <form method="POST">
            
                        <div class="mb-3">
                             <button  type='button'  id ="btnnew">submit</button>
                              <p></p>
        
                        </div>
    
            
    
                    </form>
                </div>
    
        
    </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="SBCtab">C# is also a programming language</div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="ctbtab">MySQL is a databased mostly used for web applications.</div>
    
      <div class="tab-pane" id="jquerytab">jQuery content here </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="bootstab">Bootstrap Content here
      <ul>
      <li>Bootstrap forms</li>
      <li>Bootstrap buttons</li>
      <li>Bootstrap navbar</li>
      <li>Bootstrap footer</li>
      </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="htmltab">Hypertext Markup Language</div>  
      
    </div>
    </div>
    
    
     
    
    
      </div>
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
        </div>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
    
    
    <script>
    
    
    
      $(window).load(function() {
        $('#loading').hide();
      });
    
    
      $("#btnnew").confirm({
      
      title: "Delete confirmation",
      text: "This is very dangerous, you shouldn't do it! Are you really really sure?",
      confirm: function(button) {        
        console.log('AJAX request in progress...');
        
        $('#loading').show();
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'testme.php',
          success: function(data) {
            $("p").text(data);
          },
          complete: function() {      
            $('#loading').hide();
          }
        });
        
      },
      cancel: function(button) {
        console.log("You aborted the operation.");
      },
      confirmButton: "Yes I am",
      cancelButton: "No"
    });
    
    
    
    
    
      
    
        
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `$(document).load(function() {});`

with

`$(function() {});` or `$(document).on('load', function() {})`

Because `.load()` is **Deprecated**, See the [Bug #11733](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11733)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <title>Dashboard</title>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Sliding-Confirm-Dialog-Plugin-with-jQuery-Bootstrap-Confirm/jquery.confirm.js"></script>
    <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm//vega@5"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm//vega-lite@4.8.1"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm//vega-embed@6"></script>




</head>





<body style=" background-color: #F0F8FF">

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <h2>Dashboard</h2>




        </div>
        <div class="main_content">

            <div id="loading">
                <img id="loading-image" src="./assets/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." />
            </div>
            <?php
            include "adminHeader.php";
            ?>



            <div class="mytabs">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#summarytab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Summary</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#SSWtab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">SSW KPI Monitoring</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#SBCtab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">SBC KPI Monitoring</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#ctbtab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">CTB KPI Monitoring</a></li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Web <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#jquerytab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">jQuery</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#bootstab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Bootstrap</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#htmltab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">HTML</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>



            <div class="mytabs">
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="summarytab">Write something for home tab</div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="SSWtab">



                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">

                                <form method="POST">

                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <button type='button' id="btnnew">submit</button>
                                        <p></p>

                                    </div>



                                </form>
                            </div>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="SBCtab">C# is also a programming language</div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="ctbtab">MySQL is a databased mostly used for web applications.</div>

                    <div class="tab-pane" id="jquerytab">jQuery content here </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="bootstab">Bootstrap Content here
                        <ul>
                            <li>Bootstrap forms</li>
                            <li>Bootstrap buttons</li>
                            <li>Bootstrap navbar</li>
                            <li>Bootstrap footer</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="htmltab">Hypertext Markup Language</div>

                </div>
            </div>





        </div>







    </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>


<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#loading').hide();
    })


    $("#btnnew").confirm({

        title: "Delete confirmation",
        text: "This is very dangerous, you shouldn't do it! Are you really really sure?",
        confirm: function(button) {
            console.log('AJAX request in progress...');

            $('#loading').show();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'testme.php',
                success: function(data) {
                    $("p").text(data);
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $('#loading').hide();
                }
            });

        },
        cancel: function(button) {
            console.log("You aborted the operation.");
        },
        confirmButton: "Yes I am",
        cancelButton: "No"
    });
</script>
```

Comment: still same issue... I have completely removed #loading as well, But issue is there

Comment: @Codec737 I updated the answer check and run the code snippet, It should work without any problem